# How do I store game data with cookies?

Tags: javascript, data, html

Im working on a game right now, but I was wondering how I would store the game data in cookies(in javascript) where you can load it up, and resume the last spot you were at. I was looking at some other websites like w3schools, but I didn't really understand it

Comment: Local storage might be worth looking into: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use cookies. Take a look at localstorage. It is intended for storing small bits if data, that is too big for a cookie. Here is more info: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/